# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de un archivo sin extension enviado por POST?

Tags: php, post

Hola tengo una duda sobre de cómo obtener el nombre de un archivo sin extension, enviado desde POST.

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  // En esta parte tengo entendido que se obtiene el nombre completo, ejemplo: 'MiArchivo.txt'
            $nombre_completo_archivo = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         }
```

Y lo que yo busco es obtener el nombre del archivo sin extension es decir 'MiArchivo', y éste a su vez guardarlo en una variable y poder mostrarlo en pantalla.

```
//Ejemplo: 
$_variable = "MiArchivo" 
    echo "$variable";
```

Resultado: MiArchivo

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) del siguiente modo: `$mFile = pathinfo($_FILES['sel_file']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);` considero que sería particularmente útil para archivos que tuvieran más de un punto en la extensión y cosas así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una función especial para obtener el nombre de manera simple

```
<?php 

$path = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

?>
```

En caso de querer obtener la extensión

```
<?php 

$path = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usaría un explode como lo que sigue:

```
$nombre_completo_archivo  =  $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
$parte = explode(".", $nombre_completo_archivo);
echo $parte[0]; // nombre del archivo
echo $parte[1]; // extension del archivo
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

La clase **SqlFileInfo** recibe la ruta de cualquier archivo y te permite ver los detalles de ese archivo, así cómo su nombre, extensión, peso  y otras característica del archivo

```
$archivo = new SqlFileInfo('Ruta completa Aqui');
$nombre = substr($Archivo->getFilename(), 0, (strlen($Archivo->getExtension()) * -1) - 1);
$Extension = $Archivo->getExtension();
$tamaño = formatBytes($value->getSize(), 2);
```

Este método (**formatBytes($value->getSize(), 2);**) es para obtener el tamaño del archivo con el mejor tamaño,
ejemplo en vez de poner 2048KB se ve mejor si lo pones 2MB
y ademas puede ponerle la cantidad de digitos flotantes que quieras,
ejemplo 12.23 [12] es el numero entero y [23] es el numero flotante.

```
function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2){
$unit = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB"];
$exp = floor(log($bytes, 1024)) | 0;
return round($bytes / (pow(1024, $exp)), $precision) . $unit[$exp];}
```

Código para copiar y pegar

```
$archivo = new SqlFileInfo('Ruta completa Aqui');
$nombre = substr($Archivo->getFilename(), 0, (strlen($Archivo- >getExtension()) * -1) - 1);
$Extension = $Archivo->getExtension();
$tamaño = formatBytes($value->getSize(), 2);

function formatBytes($bytes, $precision = 2){
$unit = ["B", "KB", "MB", "GB"];
$exp = floor(log($bytes, 1024)) | 0;
return round($bytes / (pow(1024, $exp)), $precision) . $unit[$exp];}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: pido disculpas por la respuesta sin explicar, era mi primera vez respondiendo en está plataforma, y la imagen la puse porque no daba para poner código, pero agradezco sus aportes.                                           
Espero que mi respuesta modificada sea más clara y de su agrado, gracias por enseñarme a mejorar mis respuestas